# What is the difference between Compact Blocks, Thin Blocks, Xthin and Graphene Compression?

Tags: scalability, mempool, transaction-propagation, block-propagation-time

What is the difference between these block propagation techniques in terms of size / bandwidth & computation requirements and also compatibility & reliability?

All the above techniques try to prevent syncing data which is already available on other clients instead of just syncing the full block mined. However, in my understanding both sender and receiver have to follow some additional logic to result in the same block. Is there any statistic what impact every of the mentioned techniques has, especially when the Mempool is not yet fully synced?